# Authenticating an user using social identity provider with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Assume that a user authenticates a mobile application with Google account using Azure AD B2C. Will Azure create a local account and link the Google login with it?

How does this manage within Azure AD B2C?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "how does this manage"?

Comment: I mean the user logins. Does google auth creates a local account in B2C as a alias to the google logins.

Comment: If that's the extend of your question, the answer is "Yes, Azure AD B2C will create a local account in the Azure AD B2C directory that is associated with the account from the social IdP (in your case Google)". Pretty much what user1197563 answered. If that doesn't answer your question, please edit it to further clarify what you are asking for.

Comment: Jeeva, can you please flag this question as answered please, or further clarify what else is needed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD B2C creates a local account and then links it to the social account (Google in this case). If you look in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) > Users & Groups, you will see a new user with a username like cpim_@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com that represents the users that signed in with the social account.